# Lambda functions seem to inherit methods from the re module

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to understand this line of code:

```
s, n = re.subn('{([^{}]*)}',
               lambda m: random.choice(m.group(1).split("|")),
               s)
```

This is the function:

```
def spin(self, s):
    while True:
        s, n = re.subn('{([^{}]*)}',
                       lambda m: random.choice(m.group(1).split("|")),
                       s)
        if n == 0: break
    return s.strip()
```

The program is importing the `re` module, and it seems that `m` is inheriting `re`'s methods. How is that? Lambdas are supposed to be just nameless functions.

Nowhere in the source code is `re` being instantiated. In other words, I do not see where there is an object being created with the name `m`. Only the `lambda` within the function `spin()`.

I have done many Google searches; but no explanation of this cryptic line of code.

The whole program is [here](https://github.com/screename/Spinner/commit/3d7adf1418e402647a111c71513d6cea223abbb9).

Comment: Just a hint. For example, there's `s` used here and there in the function `spin`. Where is it created?

Comment: I guess, if you google for all parts of this code and do some print statements you will figure it out yourself. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1):

That function is being passed a match object, which has a `group`, and so on. It's not "inheriting" anything. It was just passed an object. `m` is the name of the parameter representing the passed object. The following are equivalent:

```
func = lambda x: x**2
```

And:

```
def func(x):
    return x**2
```

Another example:

```
f2 = lambda m: m.upper()
```

And:

```
def f2(m):
    return m.upper()
```

The `m` in the above example didn't "inherit" from a string. It simply refers to a string object that was passed (or is expected to be passed) to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda function is not inheriting anything.

As seen from the [documentation of `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) (which is similar to `re.subn`) -

> **re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)**
>
> ...
> **If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.**
> ...

(Emphasis mine).

In your case, the lambda function takes an argument which is `m` and then you are using `m`'s methods in the body of the lambda function.

Your lambda function is similar to -

```
def func(m):
    return random.choice(m.group(1).split("|"))
```

Here when `re.subn` calls the function, it passes the match object as the argument, and hence the code works fine.

Comment: I know the code works. That is what puzzles me the most! Can you direct me to a site where I can read up a more about this behavior. It is not that clear to me yet.